# elegant and fast operator function cpp

Tags: c++, performance, operator-overloading, operators, operator-keyword

I am currently working on a program where my goal is to have a lot of operation between two objects (of one class) as fast as possible using the least amount of storage space possible.

```
class number 
{
public:
    number(int x) :x{x} {};
    int x;

// option 1
    number operator+(number x)
    {
        return number(this->x + x.x);
    };

// option 2
    static void add(number* a, number* b, number* dest)
    {
        dest->x = a->x + b->x;
    };
};

int main()
{
    number a(2);
    number b(2);
    number c(0);

    // 4,608e-8 sec
    c = a + b;

    // 2,318e-8 sec
    number::add(&a,&b,&c);
}
```

I've considered two options:

1. using an actual operator
2. using a static function taking in three variables (including the destination) as parameters

The first is best readable, but using it on a big scale could mean a lot of needed space because a new object is initialized every run through.

I might have fixed that with option 2. By taking in a pointer to the destination and thus reusing storage space. Option 2 is kind of bulky to read and if there are more operations happening after another the code could be very hard to understand.

I've run a couple of speed and space tests.
Using an actual operator function takes 4,6e-8 seconds per run trough and 920kb storage. The void takes 2,3e-8 and 915kb.

Is there any option I am missing? If not which one is the better tradeoff between storage space, speed and readability?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to benchmark this? Also did you enable optimizations?

Comment: You are talking about a difference of .00000002 seconds.  A delay like that could be cause by almost anything.

Comment: Worrying about a single call? Really? That is textbook premature optimization, just go with the operator if it makes sense from a design point of view. No, there will not be any new object probably due to copy elision and if there was, so what? It's and int, you do not worry about creating an extra int. Let the compiler take care of producing optimized code. You are not measuring the size of this program anyway, there's ton of baggage that can get into the final ELF based on the compilation flags.

Comment: Write code in the simplest, easiest to read and maintain way that you believe will meet the project requirements. Test it. Does it meet the requirements? If yes, you're done. Move onto the next problem or go home early and relax. If it doesn't profile and isolate the bottlenecks. Complicate things as necessary to improve ONE bottleneck. Test. If requirements are now met, Done. If not profile, isolate, and improve one bottleneck.(or revert the last change if you made it worse or didn't improve the performance enough to be worth the added complication).

Comment: it is unclear what you want to achieve. Frankly, also the code fails at demonstrating it, because to add `int`s you should use `int`s and the built-in `+`, you wont get much faster and memory efficient than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct" way to worry about performance is to turn on compiler optimizations. Most of the time thats it.

Write correct and readable code. Once you have that you can measure it. If you find that one piece of code is expensive you can look at the generated assembly to understand why it is expensive.

To add two integers the most concise is:

```
int main() {
    return 2+2;
}
```

[Compiler output (gcc 9.2 with -O3)](https://godbolt.org/z/MWbj1W):

```
main:
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
```

Now you might want to wrap the integers into a class:

```
struct number {
    int x;
};

int main() {
    return number{2}.x+number{2}.x;
}
```

This adds the cost of creating instances of the class and accessing their member. Compilers output:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
```

Instead of directly using the built-in `+` you can use an `operator+`:

```
struct number {
    int x;
    number operator+(const number& other){
        return {x+ other.x};
    }
};

int main() {
    return (number{2}+number{2}).x;
}
```

This adds the cost of calling the operator. Compilers output:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
```

Your version with the static method (with minimum modifications) is this:

```
struct number {
    int x;
    static void add(number* a, number* b, number* dest) {
        dest->x = a->x + b->x;
    };
};

int main()
{
    number a{2};
    number b{2};
    number c{0};
    number::add(&a,&b,&c);
    return c.x;
}
```

This add the cost of the caller having to "prepare" the return value, because it is an outparameter. It adds the cost of indirection via pointers. It adds the cost of having a `static` method which bloats the class. Compilers output:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
```

Conclusion: Don't do premature optimizations. In the above all cost you pay is in your code and has no influence on the resulting assembly. Write readable and simple code and leave mirco optimizations to the compiler. If you have written correct code and you measured it and you realized that there is a bottleneck, then of course you can try to improve that part. Though, before doing any of that, trying to improve your `number` for the most general use case is futile. The compiler is much better at that.

*PS* Concerning your numbers (4,608e-8 sec vs 2,318e-8 sec), I have to admit that I ignored them. e-8 sec is far too little to be significant. Also for a benchmark you would need to share the exact code of the benchmark, details of which compiler you used with what options and say on what hardware you were running it. Frankly, without those details the numbers are meaningless.